# laravel 5: dynamic url with sw-precache

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, service-worker

I'm trying to adapt offline first functionality to my laravel 5.4 app.everything works fine up until the point that I need to cache my blade files more specifically I have a problem with URLs that include a wildcard. I tried a couple of ways but nothing works/this is my webpack.mix.js function that triggers the sw-precache plugin

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
        cacheId: 'pwa',
        filename: 'service-worker.js',
        staticFileGlobs: ['public/**/*.{css,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,js,html}'],
        minify: true,
        stripPrefix: 'public/',
        handleFetch: true,
        staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /mix-manifest\.json$/, /manifest\.json$/, /service-worker\.js$/],
         dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
           '/'.{slug}.'/projects' : 'resources/views/userProfile.blade.php'
         },
        navigateFallback: '/',
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\//,
                handler: 'cacheFirst'
            },
            {
                urlPattern: /^https:\/\/www\.thecocktaildb\.com\/images\/media\/drink\/(\w+)\.jpg/,
                handler: 'cacheFirst'
            }
        ],
        // importScripts: ['./js/push_message.js']
    })
    ]
});
```

with this code when I run `npm run production` it gives me a syntax error of unexpected token.

I try to do it inline like this `'/{slug}/projects' : 'resources/views/userProfile.blade.php'` and that gives me no errors when I execute `npm` but it brakes the URL when I test it on the browser.
Does anyone know how to make this work?
Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `'/'.{slug}.'/projects' ` String concatenation is done with `+` or you can use the template syntax `\`/${slug}/projects\``

Comment: still not working.the + throws error on npm run production and `/${slug}/projects` brakes the url

Answer (score 0):

you should use regular expression for that

```
'/\.*/projects' : 'resources/views/userProfile.blade.php',
```

PS: you are getting an error because Laravel mix didn't know 'slug'(should be a variable), and laravel mix is js file you must use + as concatenation operator.